# How write custom constraints with play 2.0 in java

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm searching for a description how to write custom constraints in java for playframework 2.0?
Something similar to the description in for [play 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690461/howto-write-custom-checks-validation-for-the-play-framework)
Has anyone a hint where to find it? The description in the [official doumentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaForms) is really small.

Answer (score 2):

Play 2.0 uses the Spring data binder (for Java at least). The Spring data binder uses the JSR-303 Bean Validation API. So if you want to write a custom constraint, you should write a 'JSR-303 custom constraint'.

IMO this is a pretty good tutorial to start with: [link](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/07/writng-jsr-303-custom-constraint_26.html).

Comment: Looked into the implementation of the play sources. There they extends a special validator-class and has a special annotation `@play.data.Form.Display(name="constraint.maxLength", attributes={"value"})` So it looks to me that they something more in Play